# Mysql: counting how many rows have one or more specific keywords

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to count in a table which has a VARCHAR column with different sentences how many rows have at least one matching keyword.

For example, if I want to search for "house", "cat" and "dog" and I have in the table some sentences like "house decorations", "catnip", "dog food" and "house photos", when I search for these keywords I want to get as a result 3.

I tried with

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM insr 
WHERE `Nome` LIKE 'house' 
OR `Nome` LIKE 'cat' 
OR `Nome` LIKE 'dog';
```

But the count always returns 0..

I have searched a lot for something like this, but I still haven't found anything

Comment: % for wildcards: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need wildcards for the `like`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM insr
WHERE `Nome` LIKE '%house%' OR `Nome` LIKE '%cat%' OR `Nome` LIKE '%dog%';
```

Without the wildcards, `LIKE` behaves a lot like `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM insr WHERE `Nome` REGEXP 'house|cat|dog';
```

REGEXP adds wildcard you don't need to worry for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your are looking for the exact word. You must use wildcard to find the field that contains your word like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM insr WHERE Nome LIKE '%house%' OR Nome LIKE '%cat%' OR Nome LIKE '%dog%';
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add a space in your patterns

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM insr
WHERE `Nome` LIKE '% house %' OR `Nome` LIKE '% cat %' OR `Nome` LIKE '% dog %';
```